# Telnet - why I can connect despite shortage telnet server

Tags: telnet

On Linux, when I connect from telnet from one server (client telnet) to another (there isn't telnet server) I can connect on port, which I specify (not default for telnet 23 port). I get:

Connected to myserver (ip adress).
Escape character is '^]'.

Why, despite I haven't telnet server, I can connect with telnet client?

Comment: This question would be more suitable for [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), as it's more about networking/servers.

Comment: related: [Why telnet is considered to be a protocol? Isn't it just a simple TCP send/echo program?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/552302/208590)

Answer (score 1):

You can telnet to any opening TCP port, because that only means a normal TCP connection initiation work has done.

And your input will be treated as raw data, what happens to the data depends on the program which opened that TCP port, normally as soon as it determined the client side is not sending correct data it will disconnect.